# PowerMockito how to capture a parameter passed to a mock object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I'm trying to capture a parameter passed in input to a mock object with PowerMockito, this is the code:

```
//I create a mock object
ClassMocked mock = PowerMockito.mock(ClassMocked.class);

//Create the captor that will capture the String passed in input to the mock object
ArgumentCaptor<String> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

//When the method put is executed on my mock I want the second parameter (that is a String) to be captured
Mockito.verify(mock).put(anyString(), inputDataMapCaptor.capture());

//Creates the instance of the class that I want to test passing the mock as parameter
ClassToTest instance = new ClassToTest(mock);

//Executes the method that I want to test
instance.methodToTest();

/* I know that during the execution of "methodToTest()" mock.put(String,String) will be executed and I want to get the second string parameter. */
```

When I execute the test I have an exception executing the line Mockito.verify(mock).put(...);

"Wanted but not invoked mock.put(any,Capturing argument);"

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `instance.methodToTest();` before `Mockito.verify(mock).put(anyString(), inputDataMapCaptor.capture());`

Comment: Yep you are right, I put the verify after and it works but I miss how does it work. 
If I put verify after the method to test execution how the mock knows that it has to capture the parameter?

Comment: I am not sure about the internals of PowerMockito, but it should record all the calls to the mock's methods with their parameters

Answer (score 1):

`verify()` **verifies** that the specified method call **did** take place.

You can't verify "upfront" that a method call is supposed to happen.

Thus: `verify()` needs to happen *after the facts*, not before!

Comment: Your answer is correct I accepted the one of the user chomnoue because he answered first.